# How Does Jenkins Deal With Interactive Shell Scripts?

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins

I am writing a couple Linux shell scripts that move some code around and it would be nice and simple  if these could be interactive.

The drawback is I would like to execute some of these scripts in Jenkins and am not entirely sure of how Jenkins handles user prompts within the script. I haven't been able to find much of anything on this and don't have the resources to just go ahead and test it, so any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks guys

Comment: You might want to check out [expect(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).

Comment: This is a classic issue. Interactive stuff is nice, in a limited sense, for human callers. But batch stuff is much nicer for automation (script callers). I suggest writing almost everything for batch use, really, unless you're working on a wordprocessor or something, because in the long term the superior composability of batch scripts ends up being a big win. It's not just the fact that you can build on batch scripts much more practically; it's also much easier to do automated tests with batch interfaces, so the code ends up being more reliable.

Comment: Thanks. I have been using expect, but to do what I would like there seems to be a couple odd work-arounds which I would rather avoid

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a command that Jenkins executes expects input, it will just sit there and wait for the input. The job will hang and you'll need to kill it manually. One way of coping with this is to pipe the expected input into the command, e.g.

```
echo "input" | command
```

or

```
command < file_with_input
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am actually trying to do something like `echo "Enter Password:"; read PASSWORD` and have the user enter their password on the fly. It seems like this is acceptable from what you said above (?)

Comment: The `read` would block until you kill the job manually. Given that you are storing the result in an environment variable, you could set that variable accordingly in the Jenkins job and in the script only require user input if the variable is not set.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit. The real command is an `scp` so unless you use expect it forces a prompt. You say a prompt would "block". I realize it would stop the process and wait for input, but would the user be able to respond to that prompt within Jenkins? (little bit of a Jenkins noob if you couldn't tell)

Comment: No, Jenkins jobs are non-interactive once they have been started. The only real option is to kill the job if something like this occurs.

Comment: @degausser, you can use ssh keys to get around password typing for `scp`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thanks your patience. I'll see what I can do with expect.

Comment: @CarlNorum I agree with you that keys would probably be the best course of action, but I've been instructed to go without :(

Answer (score -5):

You can run the interactive shell script from Jenkins.

Here is the documentation for that:

http://www.buildengineers.org:8080/display/Tools/Running+interactive+Shell+Script+in+Jenkins

Using `<<LimitString` option, you can run the shell script from command line.

you can give the inputs in execution section in the jenkins configuration.

hope this helps.

Comment: Good example why link only answers are so bad: your link is down

Comment: URL is not accessible